# "mean_sd" argument in add for ggdotplot returns an error (was working a few months ago)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

ggdotplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len",
 add = c("violin", "mean_sd"))
```

Returns an error:

```
Error in `stat_summary()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_pointrange()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y, ymin, and ymax or y, xmin, and xmax
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_geom_1(d)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_geom_1(..., self = self)
Error in stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_sd", color = "black", geom = "pointrange", :

ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_pointrange()` requires the following missing aesthetics: y, ymin, and ymax or y, xmin, and xmax
```

However other strings listed in the options for add still work.

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

ggdotplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len",
 add = c("violin", "mean_se"))
```

Runs correctly.

How can I make "mean_sd" to work? I had this working a few months ago so something in the package must have changed?

Comment: Works fine for me using `ggpubr 0.6.0`.

Comment: My sessionInfo() indicates that I am also using ggpubr 0.6.0. I restarted R and only executed that code and it worked so it looks like it is some conflict with another package being loaded. Thanks @stefan !

Comment: I did some rejigging of my package loading order and got it to run with the following order: "tidyverse","ggpubr","ggsignif","ggeffects". I never received notice in my package loading about any masking of mean_sd or summary_stat though so I am still not really sure why this error was occurring.